# How to force the sorting of values in certain logic

Tags: sql-server, sorting

In SQL Server, how do I force the sorting of values to appear in certain logic. As far as I understand, SQL puts Characters first, then numbers and then letters when sorting the values.

Now, I need the underscore to comes after the letter. For example, 
I have a value of `OA_G` and a range between `MRI` and `OL5`

Currently SQL puts `OA_G` between the range. But I need to force it to be outside the range.

Comment: Through [collations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support#Collation_Defn)

Comment: Show an example of your data

Comment: The root of the problem is that you have two pieces of data in a single tuple. Your "group" indicates that you have two pieces of data which violates 1NF and causes lots of pain. The best solution would be to split your data into two columns.

Answer (score 3):

Your premise seems incorrect.  Regardless of how SQL Server sorts string data, which, by the way, is controlled by the specification of the database's collation, if one were to sort this manually, the results you seek could not be achieved.  To wit:

Given the three strings, "MRI", "OL5", and "OA_G", sort these in ascending order by string value.

Of course, this would be done character-by-character, comparing each character from left to right.

Since "M" comes before "O", the first member of the sorted set would be "MRI".  Next, compare "OL5" and "OA_G".  The letter "O" is the same, so check the next position.  "L" is greater than "A" because it is the 11th character in the alphabet, and "A" is the first, so the next member would be "OA_G", leaving "OL5" as the final member.

There is no SQL Server collation order that would make this evaluation give you the results you're seeking.

Answer (score 0):

If the parts of data are like `MRI`, `OL5`, `OA_G` etc, are constants or rarely change, you can make some table like

```
Part    | Priority
MRI     | 1 
OL5     | 2 
OA_G    | 3
```

Join it with your table and `ORDER BY Priority`